# I have a new phone number but I'm getting texts from my old number

Tags: iphone, messages, text

I have a new phone number. For some reason, I'm getting text messages from my old number on the new number. How is that possible? I've also sent text messages from my new number and the recipient sees that it's coming from my old number. Wish I could post a screen shot.

I am still using the same phone. I just changed the phone number.

Also, when someone calls the new number, there's no voicemail message but if they call the old number, they hear my greeting.

Comment: How long since the number was changed? Not all systems update instantly.  12 hours should do it.

Comment: Is that Text Messages or iMessages? You could distinguish them between green and blue background

Comment: Thanks for your message. They were iMessages originally. Then the old number switched to green. The messages from the new number are blue. I know it's confusing!

Comment: I changed the number about two weeks ago.

Comment: And if I may ask who's your service provider?

Comment: T mobile. It used to be ATT

Comment: Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive -- Is the old phone number listed in there? The new number **should** be in there, and the old number should **not**.

Answer (score 3):

It might be because your old phone number is still tied to your iMessage. Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive and unselect your old phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Switching carriers requires you to switch Sim cards so therefore chances of them being related to an iMessage issue rather than generic text message is more feasible since this is also a new phone number therefore I'd suggest you to follow the guide within [this Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349#unlink) in order to fix this issue.

In worst case scenario you might have to Reset your Network Settings which you could do but following [this Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201415).

I hope that it all works out for you.

Comment: Thanks. It is a new SIM card. The old SIM card was on a shared plan with my ex. I'm not sure how they could still be linked so I'm not sure if the info in the docs you sent me applies. What do you think?

Comment: They might very possibly be and now that you mentioned about your ex if I would be you I'd use a complete different Apple ID or at least change the password of the current one if you even hesitate that she might have your credentials