# After former owner signed out and took out her SIM, I inserted my SIM and created a new Apple ID, why does iPhone still shows former owner's files?

Tags: iphone

My daughter gifted me her iPhone X. First, she signed out her Apple ID. Then, she took her SIM card out of this iPhone X.

I took my SIM card out of my Android, which I inserted into iPhone X. I created a new Apple ID. I went  ["to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive", and unselected her old phone number.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309713) My SIM is working on this iPhone X, as I can receive and place calls.

##### But why am I still seeing my daughter's Calls, Contacts, Messages, Photos?

To save time, I don't want to ["hand-pick through the data, removing the ones you do not want"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253269449?answerId=253269449021#253269449021).

Comment: Your data isn’t tied to the SIM. You need to wipe the phone to erase the data.